# Why we will get "Could not load quick look data for "" in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

Though i added subView to the containerview.

**Printing description of containerView:**

```
<UIView: 0x7fd800b0a1a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6040006251e0>
```

Why i am getting view frame as (0 0; 0 0)

```
UIView* containerView = [UIView new];
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[containerView addSubview:contentView];

[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[contentView]-15-|" options:0
metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView)]];

[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]-15-|" options:0
metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView)]];
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the above code in your `UIViewController`/`UIView` lifecycle? Where is the breakpoint relative to that?

Answer (score 1):

You created view with zero frame. Use other initializer:

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h)];
```

But after you add view as subview its frame will still be wrong. The right frame will be after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (for ViewController) or `layoutSubviews` (for View)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

`containerView`  is not yet added to a view , it's logical not to add a subview to it until itself finds a parent like

```
 [self.view addSubview:containerView]
```

Your problem is you are trying to constraint a view (contentView) to another (containerView ) that hasn't been yet know it's position

```
UIView* containerView = [UIView new];
```

change to this

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,35)];
```

Always when you create a view programmatically the parent view has it's layout ready to add subviews to it and hook constraints between them

Also programmatically created constraints when VC launches can only be in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if(Once)
    { 
       // Add constraints here
       Once = NO
       [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```